# Why I can't remove inline style from element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to remove the opacity style entirely from the element after all the animation is complete.
http://jsfiddle.net/SthJy/1/

I tried setting `css('opacity', '')` and `removeAttr('style')` but no effect, the inilne style is still there. 
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You can animate it back to opacity 1 with a duration of 0

Comment: Well, there's no `style` attribute, so I suspect that wouldn't work. Why do you need to explicitly remove it, though?

Comment: I needed to remove it because I have :hover class on it which wasn't working with the inline style. @charlieftl answer solved it.

Comment: what about .foo:hover { opacity: 0.5 !important } ?

Comment: didn't think of it :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delay` won't work for `css()` or `removeAttr()` since they are not queueable. Read more in `delay()` docs

You need to use `css()` or `removeAttr()` within complete callack of final animation

```
 $("#helpCloud").animate({opacity: 1}, 200)
                .delay(2200)
                 .animate({  opacity: 0 }, 200, function(){
                      setTimeout(function(){
                          $(this).removeAttr('style');
                      }, 300);
                 });
```

Since default opacity of the element is zero in css, not sure what you are expecting to see

API refernce: http://api.jquery.com/delay

Comment: by using setTimeout() you get out of sync with the jQuery animation queue. consider what will happend if you want to add another animation after it? using .queue(), or attach callback to .delay() will solve it.

Comment: @treeFlute it's the last animation so what difference does it make?

Comment: here, you're right, it make no change, but it good practice to do not break the sync.

Comment: @TreeFlute that's like saying jQuery doesn't need a complete callback for `animate`. As with many aspects of working with DOM there are different approaches

Answer (score 2):

by using .queue() you are keep on it sync with the animation.

```
$("#helpCloud").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200)
            .delay(2200)
            .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200)
            .delay(300)
            .queue(function(next) {
              $(this).css('opacity', '');
              alert('happend only after .delay is over');
              next()
             })
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SthJy/3/

another way to get the same results it to use callback on .dalay(300, function() {});

```
$("#helpCloud").animate({ opacity: 1 }, 200)
                .delay(2200)
                .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 200)
                .delay(300, function() {
                  $(this).css('opacity', '');
                  alert('happend only after .delay is over');
                });
```

live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SthJy/4/